# Customizing Sipdroid

Tags: android, sip, sipdroid

I have a Voip based app. So i thought of customizing SipDroid open source project. As the starting phase i have changed all the package names, Class names etc. It perfectly works on my Samsung Galaxy Y. But i tried with many other mobiles, Voice is not audible. Call is being initialized but could not hear voice. In Samsung galaxy young, voice is clearly audible for both incoming and outgoing calls. But in all the other phones i have tested i can hear only beep sounds. What could be the problem?

EDIT:
I tried calling the other mobile(that has Sip Droid) with my Samsung Galaxy Young(customized app) I could hear voice in my app but could not hear in Sipdroid. But when i tried calling Sipdroid to Sipdroid, it works fine in all the mobiles.

EDIT:

```
Btw, There is no difference between SipDroid call and the call in my app.
```

EDIT:
I have noticed that even the SipDroid Project is not working. Only Sipdroid app(in the market) is working.

Comment: Hi that's too vague and could be caused by a lot of things. My pure guess would be that the SDP negotiation is failing for some reason. It's possible to fail in only 1 direction, which can explain why you sometimes hear audio in 1 direction only.

Comment: no... i can hear audio both in outgoing and incoming calls when i use samsung galaxy young and can not hear anything when i use any other mobile(whether its outgoing or incoming)

Comment: I dont have much idea about protocols. I can post my code here will you go through it if there are any issues?

Comment: So you're saying this: SipDroid works on all phones. You have forked the sipdroid code, changing packets and class names, and after this modifications, it works only in some cases(Galaxy Y)... so probably you have done some modifications that broke the logic. If you had taken closer look at the code, you would see there are special cases for Samsung devices, especially in codecs negotiation etc. I think it would be too much work for me to go through all the code, sorry.

Comment: yeah exactly. but the same thing before changing package names was working fine. I didnt do anything that broke logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I used [CSipSimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/) instead of Sipdroid. Its working fine.

Comment: when i am trying to import CSipSample into my eclipse i am getting lot of errors, still i am unable to sole those. can you help me on that....

Comment: can copy those files into a new android project? when i import that folder what i was downloaded from svn it creates 4 projects non of them working..

Comment: Please help me on this i m working on this from 1 month still i am facing problems..please.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy ,Seshu Vinay: Did you implemented this code me also facing same issue while importing right now I am using IMSDroid for app but as I have to implement secure calling with TLS so i have littel confusion as I seen the CSIPSimple setup here http://iprouteth0.blogspot.in/2013/04/csipsimple-srtp-and-sip-tls-with.html for TLS if you have implemented TLS than let me know I have few queries related to it.As from it I will implement it in IMSDroid

Answer (score 0):

If you wanto use CSipSimple from sources, firstly you must compile pjsip source libraries using an linux workstation.
See this link: [HowToBuild CSipSimple using Linux workstation](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild#For_Linux)